# How can I sent relevant email by using Amazon SES?

Tags: amazon-ses

I am using Amazon SES server for sending notifications emails to my users. I have verified email and verified domain. So SES_Client is sending emails successfully.

Here is my code:

public function send($subject, $recipients, $body, $senderName){

```
    $response = $this->SESClient->send_email(
        $senderName.'-noreply@example.com',
        array(
            'ToAddresses' => $recipients
        ),
        array(
            'Subject' => array(
                'Data' => $subject,
                'Charset' => 'UTF-8'
            ),
            'Body' => array(
                'Text' => array(
                    'Data' => $body,
                    'Charset' => 'UTF-8'
                ),
                'Html' => array(
                    'Data' => $body,
                    'Charset' => 'UTF-8'
                )
            )
        )
    );

    return $response->isOK();
}
```

**Problem:**

How can I pass parameters values in email text that are belongs to individual recipient in recipients array?

Is there a way at amazon server where I can create queue of my recipients and when SES server will send my email. It will replace all parameters values that belongs to each recipient.

Answer (score 0):

The `ToAddresses` field should be an array.

> Is there a way at amazon server where I can create queue of my recipients and when SES server will send my email. It will replace all parameters values that belongs to each recipient.

No, AWS and the SES service does not currently support this.

Comment: Yes I also found that they do not have support for this yet.